# Find the last row/column in excel using access VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop

I am trying to run a for loop from start to end of all of the data in my excel sheet that is being processed by access vba. I have tried:

```
myWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).row
```

but it did not work. I am confused how I can get a one number output so that it is able to run in my loop successfully. Please help. Also, if you could break down the format of your answer that would really help me. Thanks

Comment: `myWorksheet.rows.count`

Comment: xlUp in Excel = -4162. In Access - Empty. Try `myWorksheet.Cells(myWorksheet.Rows.Count, 4).End(-4162).row`

Comment: I always use worksheet.usedrange. (followed by .Rows.Count).  Most of the time you only care about rows with data in them, and UsedRange is the smallest rectangle accommodating all.

Comment: What does *but it did not work* mean? Have you created a reference to the `Microsoft Excel 1x.0 Object Library` (My `x` is `16`, yours may be different)? Could you share your complete code? `xlUp` works on my end, but you definitely have to use `myWorksheet.Rows.Count`.

Answer (score 3):

Access has not constant `xlUp` which has value `-4162` in Excel. In Access `xlUp` is non-declared variable with Variant type and initial value `Empty`. To use proper `End(xlUp)` in Access VBA you can write `.End(-4162)`:

```
myWorksheet.Cells(myWorksheet.Rows.Count, 4).End(-4162).row
```

Comment: Another option is to add `Const xlUp As Long = -4162`.

Comment: @BigBen Yes, it is appropriate when used repeatedly

Comment: When a reference to 'Microsoft Excel x.xx Objec Libray` is added, the `xlUp` constant has the same  value like in Excel. If using late binding, the constant does not mean anything for Access, indeed. He must show the whole  code. That code line may raise the same error even if `rows.count` is not fully qualified (like in your code). Excel accepts the sheet missing, but Access not.

Answer (score 0):

I usually define my `LastRow` like so, with "N" that's just the column that has the data in it, you can adjust that as needed:

`LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row`

I usually pair that with a `Dim row_no As Long` and use it in the loop like so, the hard number here being the first row of my dataset.

```
For row_no = 5 to LastRow
   'Do the thing
Next
```

There's way to iterate through loops in reverse order, which makes more sense when you're deleting rows, because when you delete it row it messes with what row the macro thinks it's on. Ie: you delete row 2, so row 3 moves to row 2, but the macro moves to row 3 which has the 4th row of data. For those you'll approach it like so:

```
For x = LastRow To 5 Step -1
    'Do the thing
Next x
```